# SQL help i need to find the inventory remaining in my office

Tags: sql

In sql help i have 3 tables, table one is asset table which is as follow

| id | asset_code | asset_name | asset_group | asset_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 | demo asset | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | A002 | demo asset 2 | 6 | 3 |

and another table is asset_allocation

| id | asset_id | allocated_quantity | allocated_location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | IT office |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | main hall |

the last table is asset_liquidated which will present assets that are no longer going to be used

| id | asset_id | liquidated_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

lets say i have 5 computers and i have allocated 3 computers and 1 is no longer going to be used so i should be remaining with 1 computer so now how do i make sql auto generate this math for me

Comment: You would simply join your tables and add/subtract/sum values accordingly. Include your query in the question and explain where it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this helps

```
SELECT
asset_quantity AS Total_Assets
,ISNULL(allocated_quantity, 0) allocated_quantity
,ISNULL(liquidated_quantity, 0) liquidated_quantity
FROM asset
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
 SELECT
asset_id, SUM(allocated_quantity) AS allocated_quantity
 FROM asset_allocation
GROUP BY asset_id
) asset_allocation2
ON asset_allocation2.asset_id = asset.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
 SELECT
asset_id, SUM(liquidated_quantity) AS liquidated_quantity
 FROM asset_liquidated 
GROUP BY asset_id
) asset_liquidated 2
ON asset_liquidated 2.asset_id = asset.id
```

Comment: like i need to know how many assets are located, unlocated and assets that are removed

Comment: I updated it now to display total, allocated and liquidated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregation and the join your tables -

```
SELECT id, asset_code, asset_name, asset_group, asset_quantity,
       asset_quantity - COALESCE(AA.allocated_quantity, 0) - COALESCE(AL.liquidated_quantity, 0) available_quantity
  FROM asset A
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT asset_id, SUM(allocated_quantity) allocated_quantity
               FROM asset_allocation
              GROUP BY asset_id) AA ON A.id = AA.asset_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT asset_id, SUM(liquidated_quantity) liquidated_quantity
               FROM asset_liquidated
              GROUP BY asset_id) AL ON A.id = AL.asset_id
```

This query will give you -1 as available_quantity for asset_id 1 as you have only 5 available, 3 of them are allotted and 3 are liquidated as per your sample data.